# firewalld port still open after removing port and services

Tags: linux, security, centos, firewalld

I have created a script to install and configured firewalld on Centos 7.

Most of the rules have worked correctly, but the SSH port still shows as Open when running a nmap scan. I know this is not a big deal and that changing ports is just security by obscurity but would like to know why.

```
firewall-cmd --zone=dmz --add-masquerade --permanent

firewall-cmd --zone=dmz --add-interface=eth0

firewall-cmd --zone=internal --add-port=${MONGO}/tcp --permanent

firewall-cmd --zone=internal --add-port=${CHAT}/tcp --permanent

firewall-cmd --zone=internal --add-port=${NFS_CLIENT}/tcp --permanent

firewall-cmd --zone=internal --add-port=${NODE_EX}/tcp --permanent

firewall-cmd --zone=dmz --add-forward-   port=port=${22}:proto=tcp:toport=${22123} --permanent

firewall-cmd --zone=dmz --add-port=${RSSH}/tcp --permanent --permanent



Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-10-04 17:33 BST
Nmap scan report for 
Host is up (0.45s latency).
Not shown: 997 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
8083/tcp open   us-srv
8086/tcp closed d-s-n


sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
dmz (active)
target: default
icmp-block-inversion: no
interfaces: eth0 eth1
sources: 
services: 
ports: 22123/tcp 8086/tcp 8083/tcp
protocols: 
masquerade: yes
forward-ports: port=22:proto=tcp:toport=22123:toaddr=
source-ports: 
icmp-blocks: 
rich rules:
```

All ideas welcome. Thanks

Comment: You have port 22123 open, and port 22 forwarded to 22123, so when `nmap` is testing port 22, its probes actually report the status of the port 22123.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to remove the ports you are forwarding, however, forwarding a port, doesn't actually close it.  Try this code:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --remove-port=22/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
```

When you call `sudo firewall-cmd --list-all`, it will no longer show the port you have removed under the listed ports and the forwarding will still work. Unfortunately, the port will still show as open for `nmap`. I don't think it's possible to prevent that, without removing the port forwarding. If I find a solution, I will update my answer.